# Using Clang++ in Makefile in place of G++

Tags: makefile, g++, clang

I have a makefile that builds my project just fine with g++ 4.6.

```
#specify the compiler  
GXX=g++ -std=c++0x

# Specifiy the target  
all: linkedList

# Specify the object files that the target depends on  
# Also specify the object files needed to create the executable  
linkedList: StudentRecord.o Node.o LinkedList.o  ListMain.o
    $(GXX) StudentRecord.o Node.o LinkedList.o  ListMain.o -o linkedList

# Specify how the object files should be created from source files  
LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp
    $(GXX)  -c  LinkedList.cpp

ListMain.o: ListMain.cpp
    $(GXX)  -c  ListMain.cpp

StudentRecord.o: StudentRecord.cpp
    $(GXX)  -c  StudentRecord.cpp

Node.o: Node.cpp
    $(GXX)  -c  Node.cpp
```

When I change the first line to be `GXX = clang++ -std=c++0x` clang throws some rather dense error about iostream not finding the correct args or something along with many other errors after that (but this is the "root" error).

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/char_traits.h:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:60:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:53:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/type_traits:630:59: error: '_Tp' does not refer to a value
    : public integral_constant<bool, __is_standard_layout(_Tp)>
```

Is this a problem with my makefile, or is could there really be a difference in this simple compilation?

Using clang 2.9.

**Note:** The line that clang is complaining about is `#include <iostream>`

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) seems to indicate that clang 2.9 isn't 100% ready for c++0x - maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: Its not crashing on a c++0x issue, it is crashing on including iostream I think

Comment: The paths in error message look like you're getting g++4.6's header files rather than clang's header files.  The g++ header files tend to use gcc-specific extensions and stuff that probably won't work with clang.

Comment: Add the -v flag to get clang to print out all the arguments it's using. Then you can run those commands manually and change the options to see if you can get individual translation units to build, and if so then change the makefile to use the settings you discover.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but in case any one else stumbles in here, one thing to check is whether you're using the clang std lib.  For that you need the flag:

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: How to add this to a Makefile ?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects If you are using autotools, you would do something like `./configure CPPFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`.  This will generate the Makefile with the flag in place. Otherwise, if you are manually editing the Makefile, it is a parameter of where CXX is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OS X Lion (10.7) or Mountain Lion (10.8), use 'c++' (/usr/bin/c++) instead of using 'clang++' directly.  Even though one is a symlink to the other, clang has some smarts to set up the correct paths and compiler options to do more what you'd expect when using c++.